# How to pass value from Angular 1 to SCSS Mixins?

Tags: angularjs, sass, less-mixins

is there a way to pass value from Angular (version 1.5.2) controller to mixins in the SASS?
I do have mixin which display elements according to two input values which are accessible in controller and template.

I have tried ng-style but that does not trigger mixins.

Comment: I really don't think you can pass it except you have sass transpiler working in client browser. However the webpage must be really slow

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after interviewing a few developers I know the solution.
Probably, the best way will be dedicated directive for that element and inside calculation of inline css.
SASS/LESS are preprocesors, so code is compiled to css - it is impossible to invoke mixin after that process.